# Eliminate the "\u3000" error in java

Tags: java, unicode, ascii, chinese-locale

When I try to compile a java file, the compiler said "illegal character \u3000",

[image]

after searching, I find it is **[CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)**
Chinese Korean and Japanese's SPACE. Instead of deleting the special SPACE manually, I decide to code a simple search-and-deleting java file to eliminate it.

However It doesnot point out the index error.
So how to write a code to eliminate this special SPACE

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class BufferReadAFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //BufferedReader br = null;
        String sCurrentLine;
        String message = "";
        try {

            /*br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/apple/Test/Instance1.java"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                message += sCurrentLine;
            }
            */
            String content = new Scanner(new File("/Users/apple/Coding/Instance1.java")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            //System.out.println(content);
            searchSubString(content.toCharArray(),"\\u3000".toCharArray());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }


    public static void searchSubString(char[] text, char[] ptrn) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        // pattern and text lengths
        int ptrnLen = ptrn.length;
        int txtLen = text.length;

        // initialize new array and preprocess the pattern
        int[] b = preProcessPattern(ptrn);

        while (i < txtLen) {
            while (j >= 0 && text[i] != ptrn[j]) {
                j = b[j];
            }
            i++;
            j++;

            // a match is found
            if (j == ptrnLen) {
                System.out.println("found substring at index:" + (i - ptrnLen));
                j = b[j];
            }
        }
    }


    public static int[] preProcessPattern(char[] ptrn) {
        int i = 0, j = -1;
        int ptrnLen = ptrn.length;
        int[] b = new int[ptrnLen + 1];

        b[i] = j;
        while (i < ptrnLen) {            
                while (j >= 0 && ptrn[i] != ptrn[j]) {
                // if there is mismatch consider the next widest border
                // The borders to be examined are obtained in decreasing order from 
                //  the values b[i], b[b[i]] etc.
                j = b[j];
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            b[i] = j;
        }
    return b;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you mean `"\u3000"` instead of `"u3000"`? I would just use `content = content.replace('\u3000', ' ');` to replace it everywhere.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey typo error just now, I have edited on my question. my real code is content.replace("\\u3000", " ")  since  the \ is special character

Comment: Good point, this will only work for valid Java characters and the point of the question is that this character is not. So you need to use the String version `content = content.replaceAll("\\u3000", " ");`

Comment: Thank you @PeterLawrey, it is a good point to bring `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`. \\u3000 is not a normal string, It is actually a Full-Width space that used in CJK. I have already elaborate it on my answer.

Comment: A screenshot of the error is not necessary. Just a text copy is needed

Comment: @Sheldon it sounds like a bug if an CJK full-width space is not a WhiteSpace and allowed in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `"\\u3000"` is what you want. You can print out the string and see the content yourself. You should use `"\u3000"` instead. Note the single back slash.

```
System.out.println("\\u3000"); // This prints out \u3000
System.out.println("\u3000");  // This prints out the CJK space
```

Alternatively, you could just use the actual CJK space character directly as in one of the `if` checks in your `CheckEmpty` class.

Comment: Notice the special space is difficult to recognize and \ is escape character, in order to detect "\" we need to add one more "\"

Comment: I understand what you mean.  But see my modified answer and try the 2 lines of code yourself.

Comment: Thank you @neurite I try it and it success

Answer (score 1):

In my Question, I am trying to use [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) alogrithm to search the index of a pattern in my java file

if we use `"\\u3000".toCharArray()` the compiler will look through each character. Which is not what we want. `\\u3000` is an **[special white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)**. It is **[FULL-WIDTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms)** space that only existed in Chinese Korean and Japanese languages.

If we trying to write sentence by using the **FULL-WIDTH** Space. It will look like:

> Ｈｅｒｅ　ｉｓ　Ｆｕｌｌ－ｗｉｄｔｈ　ｄｅｍｏｎｓｔｒａｔｉｏｎ．

Very distinctive space. but is not so visible in java file. It inspire me to write the code below

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;


public class CheckEmpty{
        public static void main(String []args){
            try{
                 String content = new Scanner(new File("/Users/apple/Coding/Instance1.java")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                if(content.contains(" ")){
                     System.out.println("English Space");
                }
                if(content.contains("\\u3000")){
                     System.out.println("Backslash 3000");
                }

                if(content.contains("　")){// notice the space is a SPECIAL SPACE
                     System.out.println("C J K　ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ");
                    //Chinese Japanese Korean white space
                }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
}
```

As expected, the result shows:

[image]

which means the java file contains both the **normal and full-width** Space.

After that I am thinking to write another java file to delete all the special space:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class DeleteTheSpecialSpace {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //BufferedReader br = null;
    String sCurrentLine;
    String message = "";
    try {


        String content = new Scanner(new File("/Users/apple/Coding/Instance1.java")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        content.replaceAll("　",""); // notice the left parameter is a SPECIAL SPACE
        //System.out.println(content);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "/Users/apple/Coding/Instance1.java" );
        out.println(content);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

}
```

Finally: amazing things happen, There is no error in "Instance1.java", since all full-width space have been eliminated
[image]
Compile SUCCESS :)