# How to read correctly Japanese characters from a file without (escape sequences) "\ufeff" and "\u3000" values in strings?

Tags: python

I have the next Japanese text which I have to separate in strings by their lines ('\n').
The text is called 'sonnet.txt'

```
さよなら夜の教室
```

Once I open the file and split the text to an array of lines.

```
file = open('sonnet.txt', encoding="utf-8")
jP = file.read().split('\n')
```

I've got the next result in the python prompt for the list.

```
>>> jP
['\ufeffさよなら\u3000夜の教室',]
```

Is there a way possible to get rid of the "\ufeff" and "\u3000" parts, not for this stored value, but in general for other kinds of words? Thank you.

Comment: You're only seeing the escape sequences because you're looking at a list, the `str()` of which is built out of the `repr()` of its elements (you couldn't tell exactly what was in the list otherwise).  If you printed out an individual element from that list, or `.join()`-them into a single string, you would see only the Japanese test.

Comment: jP = file.read().replace('\ufeff', '').replace('\u3000', '').split('\n')

Comment: Just replace those characters with nothing before spliting

Comment: I will read about escape sequences. I needed them for comparison, so those escape sequences does get in the way. Thank you! @jasonharper

Comment: Hopefully this method is valid for every word. Many thanks @PeymanMajidi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I wrote your code and made `sonnet.txt` text file, but I didn't get the same result.

My output was: `['さよなら夜の教室']`

By the way, I suggest doing like this:

```
file = open('sonnet.txt', encoding="utf-8")
jP = file.read().replace('\ufeff', '').replace('\u3000', '').split('\n')
print(jP)
```

More info:

[Eliminate the “\u3000” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556679/eliminate-the-u3000-error-in-java)

[Unicode Character 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE' (U+3000)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unicode%20Character%20%27IDEOGRAPHIC%20SPACE%27%20(U%2B3000)&rlz=1C1PDZP_enIR826IR826&oq=Unicode%20Character%20%27IDEOGRAPHIC%20SPACE%27%20(U%2B3000)&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)